# Can I use the Report Builder with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express for the development environment whereas I have SQL Server Enterprise Edition on the server. I want now to generate reports using Report Builder with SQL Server Express then deploy it to the server. So can I use it with the Express Edition?

According to this [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx); it shows that the Express Edition has some of the reporting capabilities such as report designer.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Builder as in ssrs (bids) is not included int the Express Edition.
You can let users create their own reports via the Report builder based on predefined reporting models, for that you will have to create reporting models in BIDS (which is not included in Express).